# Check if 2 vars are not in array in php

Tags: php, arrays

This is one is confusing me.
I am trying to check if 2 vars are not in an array with an OR, but it returns the opposite results than the expected.

Does 2 !in_array, in conjunction with an OR, creates 2 negatives = positive?

The case:

```
$user->groups = array(2,13,15);

if ( !in_array(2, $user->groups) || !in_array(0, $user->groups) ) {

    echo "Not in Array";

    } else {

    echo "In Array";

    }
```

Since 2 is in the array, I expect the script to echo "In Array", but it echoes "Not in Array". If I remove the second !in_array after the OR, it echoes "In Array". If I change the OR with an AND, it echoes "In Array".
It doesn't make much sense, or I am just that confused at the moment. 
Can someone give some input?

Comment: If you want to make sure that both are not in the array, that should be `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: ...If both of them are not in the array, still _either_ of them is also not in the array, so the first condition is met with `||`. Use `&&` instead.

Comment: Alternatively, keep the OR (||), remove the negation (!), and switch your two echos.

Comment: Don't they teach De Morgan's Laws in schools any more? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws

Comment: Is your problem solved? If you require any further clarification, please consider editing your question to make your requirements clearer. Otherwise you should accept an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are using `||` instead of `&&`. What the logical OR (`||`) does is that it checks the first condition and if it is true then it does not test the other conditions in the `if` statement. Here is the revised code:

```
$user->groups = array(2,13,15);

if ( !in_array(2, $user->groups) && !in_array(0, $user->groups) ) {

    echo "Not in Array";

    } else {

    echo "In Array";
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if ( !in_array(2, $user->groups) && !in_array(0, $user->groups) ) {
  echo "Not in Array";
} else {
  echo "In Array";
}
```

This will ensure that when both (&&) 0 and 2 are not in the array, it prints "Not in array"

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my comment, you should be checking that the first value `and` the second value are not in the array: `!in_array(2, $user->groups) && !in_array(0, $user->groups)`.

For two conditions, I would consider the following suggestion overkill but you may find it useful if you want to search for a larger number of values:

```
$arr = array(1,2,3);
$search = array(1,2);

$all_in = function($prev, $curr) use ($arr) {
    return $prev && in_array($curr, $arr);
};

if (array_reduce($search, $all_in, true)) {
    echo 'all values in $search are in $arr';
}
else { 
    echo 'some of the values in $search are not in $arr';
}
```

`array_reduce` applies the callback function `$all_in` to each of the values of the `$search` array and keeps track of a boolean value (initialised to `true`) that remains `true` as long as all the values are in the array `$arr`.

As I said, this approach isn't particularly useful if you're only looking for two values but one benefit is that you can easily add values to the `$search` array without changing any of the other code.